# Sorting array of different objects

Tags: swift

```
myArray = [cat, red ,dog, blue, horse, yellow tiger, green ]
```

How can I sort this array such that colour is displayed first followed by animals like this:

```
myArray = [red, blue, yellow,  green, cat,  dog, horse, tiger]
```

Comment: Just sort by type

Comment: What are the values in your array exactly? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an String array, you can use array of struct with enum to differentiate your custom type priority, as such:

```
enum MyType: Int {
    case color, animal // Prioritize your custom type here, in this example color comes first, than animal
}

struct MyData {
    let type: MyType
    let text: String
}
```

Sort array using custom type data:

```
var array: [MyData] = [
    MyData(type: .animal, text: "cat"),
    MyData(type: .color, text: "red"),
    MyData(type: .animal, text: "dog"),
    MyData(type: .color, text: "blue"),
    MyData(type: .animal, text: "horse"),
    MyData(type: .color, text: "yellow"),
    MyData(type: .animal, text: "tiger"),
    MyData(type: .color, text: "green"),
]
array.sort { $0.type.rawValue < $1.type.rawValue }
```

Output:

```
print(data.map{ $0.text })
// ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "cat", "dog", "horse", "tiger"]
```